# How to constraint compatibility with PHP without explicitly constraint all the depending packages

Tags: composer-php

I got this requirement in my `composer.json`:

```
"php": ">= 5.6",
"symfony/http-foundation": "^3.0"
```

The problem with that configuration is that it will install `paragonie/random_compat` v9.99.99 which is only compatible with PHP 7 and more. But the thing is that I don't want my `composer.lock` file to require PHP 7, I want it to still be compatible with PHP 5.6.

The solution I found is to track down which package was pulling this dependency and, once I found it, I added this to my requirements:

```
"paragonie/random_compat": "~2.0"
```

But I wonder if there is not a better way of doing that: somehow telling that I accept all the versions above PHP 5.6, but I don't accept packages that would force to have PHP 7?

Comment: This is `composer.json` of your project, or just a library/dependency?

Comment: It's from my project (https://github.com/MightyCreak/mesamatrix/blob/master/composer.json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make `composer.lock` compatible with PHP 5.6, you have at least two options to achieve that:

1. Use PHP 5.6 for `composer update` - you should be able to install multiple versions of PHP on your OS and run Composer like this:

   ```
   /path/to/php6.5 /path/to/composer update
   ```
2. Use [`platform`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) settings in `composer.json` to force installation for specific version regardless PHP version used to run Composer commands:

   ```
   "config": {
       "platform": {
           "php": "5.6.38"
       }
   },
   ```