# How can we change version requirements for dependency on composer.lock file?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a dependency package that requires following dependencies, in my `composer.lock` file.

```
"require": {
            "evenement/evenement": "^3.0 || ^2.0 || ^1.0",
            "php": ">=5.3.0",
            "react/dns": "^0.4.13",
            "react/event-loop": "^1.0 || ^0.5 || ^0.4 || ^0.3.5",
            "react/promise": "^2.6.0 || ^1.2.1",
            "react/promise-timer": "^1.4.0",
            "react/stream": "^1.0 || ^0.7.1"
        },
```

With that pipe symbol, if I `composer install`, what version i.e. `^3.0`, `^2.0` or `^1.0`, will get installed?

Also, I am having issue with php version compatibility issue and hence want this package to install its dependencies with certain versions only.

Say, I want to remove `^3.0` from the require key. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Composer will install dependencies which match all requirements of all dependencies (and root project). The easiest way to narrow allowed versions is to add more restrictive constraints into `composer.json` of your root project. For example:

```
"evenement/evenement": "^2.0 || ^1.0",
```

Since now 3.0 line will not be installed, because it is not allowed by your root package.

Regardless of PHP version compatibility - you may want to read [How to constraint compatibility with PHP without explicitly constraint all the depending packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355467/how-to-constraint-compatibility-with-php-without-explicitly-constraint-all-the-d/).

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to check docs on this matter:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#composer-versions-vs-vcs-versions

they explain how those special signs work. The pipes are specifically explained in 
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#version-range

removing dependncy is a bit problematic, but the easiest (not safest) is removing the dependeny from `composer.json`, then removing `composer.lock` file, and then running `composer update`

Comment: well the problem is that this `evenement/evenement` is a sub-dependency and is controlled by other dependency. How can I update such sub-dependencies version?

Comment: I don't think this is as easy as you would like. You would have to provide package replacements for all dependencies that require packages you don't want. i.e github.com/azima/evenement and use it in your project. `azima/evenement` would naturally not have the unwanted dependency listed in its `composer.json`.
That's why it's called dependency. if you want to use it, you are fully dependent on what the package maintainer needs. the only way is to create your own package.