# Best Practices when using composer on different PHP versions

Tags: php, composer-php

I am developing PHP app on my Mac which is using PHP 7.3, but my server is running PHP 7.1. I commit both `composer.json` and `composer.lock` into git, and contains the lines

```
 "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.0",
```

However, when I run `composer install` on my local Mac, and `composer.lock` is filling with dependencies which is optimised for my local PHP 7.3, and when I copy the `composer.lock` to the server and run the `composer install` again, will it install the correct version? eg. PHP 7.1 instead of 7.3 dependencies?

Comment: [Probably relevant.](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5163)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to constraint compatibility with PHP without explicitly constraint all the depending packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355467/how-to-constraint-compatibility-with-php-without-explicitly-constraint-all-the-d)